# Is it possible to use OverlayItem.setMarker() with no shadow?

Tags: android, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I want to display different markers on my map. One solution I could find is to define a new overlay for each marker. But then I could find that it can be done easier with

> OverlayItme.set Marker(Drawable marker);

using a single overlay. It works fine, but the markers are drawn with shadow and I would like to display the marker icon with no shadow, my original picture has no shadow, and I want to draw it as it is. is it possible?
This is how I'm doing now:

```
markerpic = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_map);
    markerpic.setBounds(0, 0, markerpic.getIntrinsicWidth(), markerpic.getIntrinsicHeight());

   GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6), (int)(lng*1E6));

    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(gp, "Title", "Message");
        overlayitem.setMarker(markerpic);
        myoverlay.adOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlay.add(myoverlay);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a subclass which extends ItemizedOverlay 
and override this in my class for removing the shadow:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        if(!shadow)
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        }
    }
```