# Dark glow on icons on Android map

Tags: android, dictionary

We're working on an Android application that shows information about parkings on a map. The problem is that the icons on the map are rendered with a "dark glow" around them.

If you see the image, the glow is surrounding most of the icons, but not all of them, and we can't find any property (i.e.: highlight) that could be responsible for such behavior. All of the icons are on the same layer.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image: map capture]

Comment: Provide some code. Are you using ItemizedOverlay? Have you tried overriding draw()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, it is a drop shadow rather than border. Did you override draw method when extending ItemizedOverlay?

Try this:

```
    public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay
{
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        if(!shadow)
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Example taken from: 
[It is possible to remove the Shadow of the Icons (items) on a googlemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327733/it-is-possible-to-remove-the-shadow-of-the-icons-items-on-a-googlemap) 
and [Is it possible to use OverlayItem.setMarker() with no shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971704/it-is-possible-to-use-overlayitem-setmarker-with-no-shadow)

Try that, make sure you declare @Override on draw method too.